# Passing params with javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php

I use the chrome extension called tubeoffline. It uses the following script to find the video src of movies from viooz.co

```
function injectJs(link)
{
   var scr = document.createElement('script');
   scr.type="text/javascript";
   scr.src=link;
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scr)
//document.body.appendChild(scr);
}
injectJs('http://www.tubeoffline.com/js/plugin/getSrc.php');
injectJs('http://www.tubeoffline.com/js/plugin/DlExec.php');
```

How do I find out the values of the parameters which are being passed ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see there are missing parameters in the URLs. Whatever parameters these should be must be somewhere in documentation... else it is just guessing

Answer (score 0):

I use Firebug for this sort of stuff, however Chrome has its own set of development tools.  I believe it's accessed the same way - by hitting your F12 button.

This will have several tabs that you can click on.  There should be a "Network" tab that shows which pages are being called.  If you refresh the page with the developer tools open, you should see what is going on behind the scenes.